# Matching sub-string of string without any order

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to match sub-strings in a string without any order in python?

Lets say I have a string

```
Hello how are you doing you have a nice day hello there
```

and my match sub-string is 'hello', 'you'.

Now I need a regex pattern that will match `hello how are you` and `you doing you(already matched shouldn't match again) have a nice day hello`

I tried something like this but didnt work

```
(hello|you)[\w\s]*?[^($1)](hello|you)
```

Expected Output:

```
Hello how are you
you doing you have a nice day hello
you have a nice day hello
```

Basically I want to match anything between 'hello...you' and vice-versa 'you...hello'

I don't how to get rid of first matched pattern. Any idea to resolve this?

Updated:

Basically my question is i need to match a string with no duplicate sub-strings. In above, sentence is "Hello how are you doing you have a nice day hello there" match-strings are "Hello", "you" hence i need to match a sub-string starting with hello and ending with you or starting with you and ending with hello, not starting with you and ending with you and same way with hello

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: I need to matching pattern that will match the following,
'hello how are you' and 'you doing you have a nice day hello'

Comment: So basically you want to match anything between `hello` and `you`?

Comment: So, `hello` got matched first then it should ends with `you` ?

Comment: @aswin post your expected output on your question

Comment: did you want `you doing you` to get matched?

Comment: Unfortunately, those two substrings overlap so you can't do this in one regex. If you're happy with 'hello how are you' and 'you have a nice day hello', you can use `hello.*?you|you.*?hello`.

Comment: I think it's any substring that starts with "hello" or "you" and goes until "you" or "hello," ending with whichever word didn't start it.

Comment: Actually, it turns out you can find overlapping matches but then it will find *all* overlapping matches: `(?=(hello.*?you|you.*?hello))`.

Comment: @avinash edited the question for expected output

Comment: Sometimes, it's easiest to do part of the work outside the regex - find (1) all the positions of "hello" and (2) all the positions of "you", and decide what that means in terms of matches separately. BTW - why are "Hello how are you doing you" and "you doing you have a nice day hello" not valid matches? Is that what you mean by "no duplicate substrings" (no "you" or "hello" between the "you" and "hello" that matched)?

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern with `re.findall`:

```
(?si)(?=((?:hello|you).*?(?:hello|you)))
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP7iF0/2)

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/ajSIjU):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?=((?:hello|you).*?(?:hello|you)))', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
test_str = "Hello how are you doing you have a nice day hello there"
print(p.findall(test_str))
# => ['Hello how are you', 'you doing you', 'you have a nice day hello']
```

Regex explanation:

- `(?si)` - enable dotall (`.` matches newline, too) and ignorecase flags
- `(?=((?:hello|you).*?(?:hello|you)))` - a positive lookahead that does not consume characters but allows *capturing* substrings at each location in the string with `re.findall`. It searches for:

  - `(?:hello|you)` - literal character sequences `hello` or `you`
  - `.*?` - any characters, 0 or more occurrences, as few as possible
  - `(?:hello|you)` - literal character sequences `hello` or `you`

To only match `hello` and `you` as whole words, you may add word boundaries `\b`:

```
(?si)(?=(\b(?:hello|you)\b.*?\b(?:hello|you)\b))
         ^^             ^^   ^^             ^^
```

Comment: Thanks stribizhev for the explanation but my question is how to avoid 'you doing you'. Lets say you have been matched once i.e. (you) doing you , can we avoid matching 'you' again ? and that will avoid you doing you,

Comment: Basically my question is i need to match a string with no duplicate sub-strings. In above, sentence is "Hello how are you doing you have a nice day hello there" match-strings are "Hello", "you" hence i need to match a string with hello and ending with you or starting with you and ending with hello, not starting with you and ending with you same way with hello

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from your question, this is probably what you want:

```
t = "Hello how are you doing you have a nice day hello there"
pattern = ["(?=hello).*?(?<=you)","(?=you).*?(?<=hello)"]
for p in pattern:
  pat = re.compile(p)
  for m in pat.finditer(t.lower()):
    print m.group()
```

Output is:

> hello how are you
>   you doing you have a nice day hello